# Developing the news area for a website

Tags: website-design, info-visualisation

I'm developing a simple website to a small company. It has a back-office (built with PHP and mySQL) for edit/ add/ remove some content like products and news.

The news has some text and an image. There is a section for linking to other news.

What is the best way to develop the news area:

1. With a single page with all the news and add some animation like show, hide, fadeIn fadeOut. (eg. when the users click in other news hide the current news and show the new one)
2. Every news has a single page. When the user clicks in other news a different page is loaded.

If someone has any doubt, just tell and I'll try to explain it better.

Comment: Could you please try explain it more clearly.  Mockups or images of what you want would help - even if they are rough sketches.

Comment: do you mean the layout at the Backend?

Comment: how big are the news articles - are they short (2-5 paras) or long (10-20 paras)?

Comment: Since the news can be inserted by the client, and I didn't recieve any information related to the extension I have to think in both cases. Anyway I already decided: I'll make one page per each news.This way the pages loads faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single page paradigm (option 1) presents a more fluid experience for the user.

Comment: yes. Thats what I made